Ignite node restarts
For the last month or so we have been having frequent Ignite node restarts. Please find attached the Ignite logs. It is clear that the JVM is running out of memory (seen in Heap Used), the CPU utilization goes up, the JVM pauses goes high and this causes the node to lose connectivity with the rest of the nodes in the cluster. This seems to trigger the restart.
No value is set specifically for setOnheapCacheEnabled. The default as per our understanding is false. Despite this an increased heap usage is seen and the nodes restart.
[11:20:04,287][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=a66811bb, name=ImportedCluster, uptime=2 days, 20:58:22.594]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=19, CPUs=89, servers=3, clients=16, topVer=31, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[100.96.17.220, 127.0.0.1], discoPort=47500, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=16, curLoad=58.57%, avgLoad=2.84%, GC=5.6%]
    ^-- Heap [used=7948MB, free=1.11%, comm=8038MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=176631]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=1, idle=15, qSize=0]
    ^-- Striped thread pool [active=14, idle=2, qSize=1090]
[11:20:04,287][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] FreeList [name=default##FreeList, buckets=256, dataPages=53711, reusePages=5711]
[11:20:04,287][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.21%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   default region [type=default, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=6429MB, usedRam=662MB, freeRam=89.7%, allocRam=667MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   volatileDsMemPlc region [type=user, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB]

[11:20:04,287][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 

Data storage metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=663MB, free=90.15%, allocated=747MB]
    ^-- Page memory [pages=168760]

[11:20:04,935][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 600 milliseconds.
[11:20:05,600][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 615 milliseconds.
[11:20:06,313][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 663 milliseconds.
[11:20:06,953][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 590 milliseconds.
[11:20:07,671][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 668 milliseconds.
[11:20:08,406][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 684 milliseconds.
[11:20:09,100][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 645 milliseconds.
[11:20:09,728][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 578 milliseconds.
[11:20:10,374][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 596 milliseconds.
[11:20:11,182][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 757 milliseconds.
[11:20:12,013][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 782 milliseconds.
[11:20:12,664][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 600 milliseconds.
[11:20:13,293][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 580 milliseconds.
[11:20:13,861][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 518 milliseconds.
[11:20:14,419][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 508 milliseconds.
[11:20:15,025][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 556 milliseconds.
[11:20:15,639][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 564 milliseconds.
[11:20:16,242][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 553 milliseconds.
[11:20:16,949][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 657 milliseconds.
[11:20:17,574][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 575 milliseconds.
[11:20:18,181][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 557 milliseconds.
[11:20:19,340][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 578 milliseconds.
[11:20:19,982][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 592 milliseconds.
[11:20:20,602][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 570 milliseconds.
[11:20:21,348][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 696 milliseconds.
[11:20:22,049][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 651 milliseconds.
[11:20:22,698][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 599 milliseconds.
[11:20:23,250][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 502 milliseconds.
[11:20:23,868][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 568 milliseconds.
[11:20:24,536][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 618 milliseconds.
[11:20:25,218][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 632 milliseconds.
[11:20:25,821][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 553 milliseconds.
[11:20:26,432][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 561 milliseconds.
[11:20:27,067][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 581 milliseconds.
[11:20:28,214][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1101 milliseconds.
[11:20:29,330][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 519 milliseconds.
[11:20:29,970][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 590 milliseconds.
[11:20:30,623][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 603 milliseconds.
[11:20:31,309][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 636 milliseconds.
[11:20:31,863][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 504 milliseconds.
[11:20:32,987][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 553 milliseconds.
[11:20:33,619][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 582 milliseconds.
[11:20:34,196][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 527 milliseconds.
[11:20:35,441][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 584 milliseconds.
[11:20:36,035][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1155 milliseconds.
[11:20:36,036][SEVERE][sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster%][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=ttl-cleanup-worker, threadName=ttl-cleanup-worker-#103%ImportedCluster%, blockedFor=14s]
[11:20:36,037][WARNING][sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster%][] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=ttl-cleanup-worker, igniteInstanceName=ImportedCluster, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1731304221348]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=ttl-cleanup-worker, igniteInstanceName=ImportedCluster, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1731304221348]
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.streams.BinaryAbstractInputStream.readByteArray(BinaryAbstractInputStream.java:44)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadByteArray(BinaryUtils.java:1241)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1995)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1889)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1880)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.unmarshal(BinaryUtils.java:1871)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.fieldByOrder(BinaryObjectImpl.java:572)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldImpl.value(BinaryFieldImpl.java:112)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.property.QueryBinaryProperty.fieldValue(QueryBinaryProperty.java:229)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.property.QueryBinaryProperty.value(QueryBinaryProperty.java:121)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.QueryIndexRowHandler.indexKey(QueryIndexRowHandler.java:93)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.IndexRowImpl.key(IndexRowImpl.java:67)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.IndexRowComparatorImpl.compareRow(IndexRowComparatorImpl.java:74)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.compareFullRows(InlineIndexTree.java:340)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.compare(InlineIndexTree.java:320)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree.compare(InlineIndexTree.java:80)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.compare(BPlusTree.java:5746)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.findInsertionPoint(BPlusTree.java:5666)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.access$1100(BPlusTree.java:215)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Search.run0(BPlusTree.java:422)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$GetPageHandler.run(BPlusTree.java:6298)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Search.run(BPlusTree.java:402)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$GetPageHandler.run(BPlusTree.java:6284)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree$1$1.run(InlineIndexTree.java:713)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexTree$1$1.run(InlineIndexTree.java:700)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.util.PageHandler.readPage(PageHandler.java:174)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.DataStructure.read(DataStructure.java:415)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.read(BPlusTree.java:6503)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.removeDown(BPlusTree.java:2411)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.removeDown(BPlusTree.java:2430)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.doRemove(BPlusTree.java:2338)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.removex(BPlusTree.java:2145)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexImpl.remove(InlineIndexImpl.java:406)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.sorted.inline.InlineIndexImpl.onUpdate(InlineIndexImpl.java:359)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.IndexProcessor.updateIndex(IndexProcessor.java:465)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.IndexProcessor.updateIndexes(IndexProcessor.java:308)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.cache.query.index.IndexProcessor.remove(IndexProcessor.java:202)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.remove(GridQueryProcessor.java:3659)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.remove(GridCacheQueryManager.java:453)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.finishRemove(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2693)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$CacheDataStoreImpl.remove(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:2670)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.remove(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:598)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.removeValue(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3947)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.onExpired(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3638)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.onTtlExpired(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3561)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheTtlManager$1.applyx(GridCacheTtlManager.java:79)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheTtlManager$1.applyx(GridCacheTtlManager.java:70)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteInClosure2X.apply(IgniteInClosure2X.java:38)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.expireInternal(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1356)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.expire(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:1313)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheTtlManager.expire(GridCacheTtlManager.java:246)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedTtlCleanupManager$CleanupWorker.lambda$body$0(GridCacheSharedTtlCleanupManager.java:199)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedTtlCleanupManager$CleanupWorker$$Lambda$1487/0x000000080082f440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.base@11.0.21/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent(Unknown Source)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheSharedTtlCleanupManager$CleanupWorker.body(GridCacheSharedTtlCleanupManager.java:198)
    at app//org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base@11.0.21/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[11:20:36,633][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 548 milliseconds.
[11:20:37,234][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 551 milliseconds.
[11:20:37,235][WARNING][sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster%][FailureProcessor] No deadlocked threads detected.
[11:20:38,232][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 604 milliseconds.
[11:20:38,841][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 559 milliseconds.
[11:20:40,058][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1163 milliseconds.
[11:20:40,638][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 534 milliseconds.
[11:20:41,222][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 534 milliseconds.
[11:20:41,849][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 577 milliseconds.
[11:20:42,467][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 568 milliseconds.
[11:20:43,688][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1171 milliseconds.
[11:20:44,267][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 529 milliseconds.
[11:20:44,868][WARNING][sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster%][FailureProcessor] Thread dump at 2024/11/11 11:20:41 IST
...
This is followed by the thread dump
...
[11:22:16,476][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=a66811bb, name=ImportedCluster, uptime=2 days, 21:00:33.661]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=19, CPUs=89, servers=3, clients=16, topVer=31, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[100.96.17.220, 127.0.0.1], discoPort=47500, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=16, curLoad=100%, avgLoad=3%, GC=44.27%]
    ^-- Heap [used=7967MB, free=0.88%, comm=8038MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=176559]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=2, idle=14, qSize=0]
    ^-- Striped thread pool [active=13, idle=3, qSize=993]
[11:22:16,476][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] FreeList [name=default##FreeList, buckets=256, dataPages=53581, reusePages=7785]
[11:22:17,019][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 
    ^--   sysMemPlc region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=99.21%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   default region [type=default, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=256MB, maxCfg=6429MB, usedRam=662MB, freeRam=89.7%, allocRam=667MB]
    ^--   TxLog region [type=internal, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=false,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=40MB]
    ^--   volatileDsMemPlc region [type=user, persistence=false, lazyAlloc=true,
      ...  initCfg=40MB, maxCfg=100MB, usedRam=0MB, freeRam=100%, allocRam=0MB]

[11:22:17,019][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#38%ImportedCluster%][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] 

Data storage metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Off-heap memory [used=663MB, free=90.15%, allocated=747MB]
    ^-- Page memory [pages=168760]

[11:22:17,591][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 2189 milliseconds.
[11:22:17,596][WARNING][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[3628f955 100.96.11.124:47500 crd]-#2%ImportedCluster%-#68%ImportedCluster%][FailureProcessor] Thread dump at 2024/11/11 11:22:15 IST

This is followed by a thread dump
...

[11:22:19,268][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1094 milliseconds.
[11:22:21,500][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 2715 milliseconds.
[11:22:22,086][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 536 milliseconds.
[11:22:23,693][WARNING][jvm-pause-detector-worker][IgniteKernal%ImportedCluster] Possible too long JVM pause: 1557 milliseconds.
[11:22:23,694][WARNING][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[3628f955 100.96.11.124:47500 crd]-#2%ImportedCluster%-#68%ImportedCluster%][CacheDiagnosticManager] Page locks dump:



































Thread=[name=sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster%, id=31], state=WAITING
Locked pages = []
Locked pages log: name=sys-stripe-0-#1%ImportedCluster% time=(1731304339806, 2024-11-11 11:22:19.806)
-> Try Read lock nextOpPageId=844420635164855, nextOpStructureId=AuthDetailsCache##PendingEntries [pageIdHex=0002ffff000000b7, partId=65535, pageIdx=183, flags=00000002]












Thread=[name=sys-stripe-5-#6%ImportedCluster%, id=36], state=RUNNABLE
Locked pages = [5693394349899988095[4f02ffff10013c7f](r=1|w=0)]
Locked pages log: name=sys-stripe-5-#6%ImportedCluster% time=(1731304339806, 2024-11-11 11:22:19.806)
L=1 -> Read lock pageId=5693394349899988095, structureId=-863187587_MESSAGE_DATA_RAW_DATA##H2Tree [pageIdHex=4f02ffff10013c7f, partId=65535, pageIdx=268516479, flags=00000002]


Thread=[name=sys-stripe-6-#7%ImportedCluster%, id=37], state=RUNNABLE
Locked pages = [844420635164855[0002ffff000000b7](r=0|w=1)]
Locked pages log: name=sys-stripe-6-#7%ImportedCluster% time=(1731304339806, 2024-11-11 11:22:19.806)
L=1 -> Write lock pageId=844420635164855, structureId=AuthDetailsCache##PendingEntries [pageIdHex=0002ffff000000b7, partId=65535, pageIdx=183, flags=00000002]





Thread=[name=ttl-cleanup-worker-#103%ImportedCluster%, id=161], state=RUNNABLE
Locked pages = [844420903612501[0002ffff10003055](r=1|w=0)]
Locked pages log: name=ttl-cleanup-worker-#103%ImportedCluster% time=(1731304339806, 2024-11-11 11:22:19.806)
L=1 -> Read lock pageId=844420903612501, structureId=dupCheckCache-p-227##CacheData [pageIdHex=0002ffff10003055, partId=65535, pageIdx=268447829, flags=00000002]



And then the JVM restarts.

The question is despite the fact that all the cache is out of heap why is the high heap utilization seen. It is very likely that the number of entries in the cache would have gone up significantly during this time. And the entries have a BLOB which is 6KB in size. Difficult to say how many entries though.
No heap dumps were generated as the Out of Memory Exception was not raised and the node restarted before this exception.
There was no Xmx configured for the node.
12-Dec-2024
Increasing heap size to 16GB did not help. But here are some additional observations based on the Ignite logs and the heap dump which we managed to generate with quite some difficulty.
In the Ignite logs we see
^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
going from 0 to a million in a matter of 10 minutes.
During the sametime the off heap storage remains almost constant
The transactions we process are max about 100 per second.
The follwing is seen in the heap dump
millions of nested entries of ConcurrentLinkedDeque leading the following leaf nodes
org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$WriteRequestImpl -> org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridMessage ->   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousMessage -> byte[].
The byte[] is about 40K to 50K in size.
Also in the heap dump it is found that there millions of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$WriteRequestImpl  with no parent.
setMessageQueueLimit is set to 0. We understand that setting it to a lower limit should reduce the chances of the above happening. But what will be the consequence of setting a limit to this. Will the clients shutdown instead of the server?
This setSlowClientQueueLimit has not been set. This has been left with the default value.

I think you should still be able to manually create a heap dumpbefore it shuts down and analyze it.

Thanks @dan1st. We could not generate a heap dump in the production. In the test environment we saw 25000+ instances of GridContinuousMessage contained in GridIoMessage contained in GridNioServer$WriteRequestImpl which in turn is contained a huge (really massive list 1000s) list of ancestors of ConcurrentLinkedDeque$Node

While your data is stored off-heap, Ignite is still a Java application and needs heap space to work. Certainly, 8Gb across 19 nodes is not enough for most use cases.
You can configure the JVM using the JVM_OPTS environment variable if you start your servers with ignite.sh. The suggested defaults in the documentation are:
-server
-Xms10g
-Xmx10g
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC

You're not using persistence, so 10Gb per server node is probably too much. I would suggest starting around 4Gb.
Next, you note that the message queue length is growing. This means that your cluster is not processing messages fast enough. We have very little information about your cluster.
Given the message queue length and the queue for the striped pool, one guess is that you're using third-party persistence and that your database has become a bottleneck.
Another guess might be that your nodes are trying to use more memory than you have available, resulting in swapping. This would slow the nodes down, resulting in pauses and slower processing of events.

At present we have not provided any Xmx. So theoretically it can take as much memory as it requires. The issue is that the GC that kicks in causes a high JVM pause (Full GC) as well as it is unable to clear any memory from the tenure even after the Full GC. It continuously is decreasing. Unable to figure out why the heap space is reducing.

Not setting -Xmx just means you're using whatever the default is. It does not mean it's unlimited.

#Stephen Darlington, you are right in saying that the memory is limited, but the issue is more to do with the GC pauses than the VM running out of memory. If it had more memory the GC pauses would only go up further exacerbating the situation. Any clues on what to look for will help.

No, more heap memory will likely eliminate the pauses. My advice remains the same.

Increased the heap size to 16GB still the problem is coming. What we are seeing is as under
